# bash script to build complex command syntax, print it first then execute - problems with variable expansion

Tags: command, sh, execute, variable-expansion

I want to create scipt to faciliate producing local text file extracts from Hive.
This is to basically execute commands like below:

```
hive -e "SET hive.cli.print.header=true;SELECT * FROM dropme"|perl -pe 's/(?:\t|^)\KNULL(?=\t|$)//g'>extract/outbound/dropme.txt
```

While the above works like a charm I find it quite problematic to implement through the parametrized following script (much simplified):

```
#!/bin/sh

TNAME=dropme
SQL="SELECT * FROM $TNAME"
echo $SQL
echo "SQL: $SQL"
EXTRACMD="hive -e \"SET hive.cli.print.header=true;$SQL\"|perl -pe 'BEGIN{if(defined(\$_=<ARGV>)){s/\b\w+\.//g;print}}s/(?:\t|^)\KNULL(?=\t|$)//g'>extract/outbound/$TNAME.txt"
echo "CMD: $EXTRACMD";
${EXTRACMD}
```

When run I get: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "e"`

I know there may be many flavours you can print the text or execute command. For instance the line `echo $SQL` prints me list of files in the directory instead:

`SELECT file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt FROM dropme`

while the next one: `echo "SQL: $SQL"` gives just what I want: `SQL: SELECT * FROM dropme`

`echo "CMD: $EXTRACMD"` prints the (almost) the command to be executed. Almost, as I see `\t` in perl code being expanded:

`CMD: hive -e "SET hive.cli.print.header=true;SELECT * FROM dropme"|perl -pe 'BEGIN{if(defined($_=<ARGV>)){s\w+\.//g;print}}s/(?:   |^)\KNULL(?=    |$)//g'>extract/outbound/dropme.txt`

Maybe that's still ok, but what I want is to be able to copy&paste this command into (other) terminal and execute as the command I put at the top. Ideally I would like that command to be exactly the same (so with `\t` there)

Biggest problem I have comes when I try to execute it (`${EXTRACMD}` line). I'm getting the error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "e"` …and so on, irrelevant as bash treats every 'word' as single command here. I assume as I don't even know what is really tries to run (prior print attempt obviously doesn't help)

I'm aware that I have multiple options, like:

- escaping special characters in the command definition string (like I did with doublequotes)
- experimenting with echo and `$VAR`, `'$VAR'` or `"$VAR"`
- experimenting with "${EXTRACMD}" or evaluating through `eval "${EXTRACMD}"`
- experimenting with `shopt -s extglob` or `set -f`

but as number of combinations is quite large and with my little bash experience I feel it's better to ask for good practice here so my question is:

**Is there a way to print a (complex/compound shell) command first and subsequently be able to execute it (exactly as per printed output)?** In this case it would be printing the exact command from the top, then executing it the same way as by manually copying that output into terminal prompt and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

Do not construct commands as strings. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 for details.

That page also talks about a built-in way of getting the shell to tell you what it is running (section 6).

If that doesn't do what you want you can also, with bash, try using `printf %q\\n "${arr[*]}"`.

Comment: Very well! What if I want the SQL variable to be passed by parameter? So executing the script as `hivedump.sh SELECT * FROM dropme` through the construct `SQL=$@` later gets expanded to `hive -e 'SET hive.cli.print.header=true;SELECT file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt FROM dropme…'` ?

Comment: @msciwoj You need to quote `*` when you use it as an argument to keep the shell from expanding it as a glob. And don't use `SQL=$@` and then use `$SQL` later that just re-creates the problem. Use `$@` *exactly* where you need it expanded.